# $P$-generated module and exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

For any $P$-generated module $N$, the canonnical exact sequence $P^{(\Lambda)}\to N\to0$ remains exact under $Hom_{R}(P,-)$

Why is this true? and is there any good reference to get more in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If with “canonical exact sequence” you mean that $\Lambda=\operatorname{Hom}_R(P,N)$, this is obvious: the morphism

$$\varphi\colon P^{(\operatorname{Hom}_R(P,N))}=P^{(\Lambda)}\to N$$

is defined by

$$\varphi\bigl((x_f)_{f\in\Lambda}\bigr)=\sum_{f\in\Lambda}f(x_f)$$

So, if you have $g\colon P\to N$ you can lift it to a morphism $\hat{g}\colon P\to P^{(\Lambda)}$ by simply using the canonical injection.